# how to force run a method in all viewControllers viewDidLayoutSubviews functions automatically?

Tags: ios, iphone, swift

say I have this extension that helps me in changing the font size in all text elements of a `UIViewController`

```
extension UIView {
    func changeFontSize(){
        let fontSize = CGFloat(5)
        if let v = self as? UIButton {
            v.titleLabel?.font = v.titleLabel?.font.withSize(fontSize)
            print("didChangeFontSizeFor_Button")
        } else if let v = self as? UILabel {
            v.font = v.font.withSize(fontSize)
        } else if let v = self as? UITextField {
            v.font = v.font?.withSize(fontSize)
        } else {
            for v in subviews {
                v.changeFontSize()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

it works fine when I call it like this

```
override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    view.changeFontSize()
}
```

now the question, is there a way where I can make this more dynamic to be forced in all viewControllers?

say we have 3 view Controllers, and I want to make some CocoaPods library where people just make a simple call like this

```
forceAppFontSize.fontSize = CGFloat(15)
```

to change the font size for all other screens..

class 1

```
import UIKit
class v1: UIViewController{
     override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
          print("someCommand1")
          print("someCommand2")
     }
}
```

class 2

```
import UIKit
class v2: UIViewController{
     override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
          print("someCommand")
     }
}
```

class 3

```
import UIKit
class v3: UIViewController{
}
```

is there a way to make this dynamic without breaking the original `viewDidLayoutSubviews` ? see class 1 for example, the view has some commands already that to be not destroyed or replaced.

Comment: You really should look into my answer on your previous question. `UIAppearance` does what you want.

Answer (score 1):

There is a much simpler way. Your actual goal is to update all views in your app. There is no need to go through each view controller. Simply call your `changeFontSize()` extension method on your app's main window.

Comment: nice idea, but, adding this self.window?.changeFontSize() to didFinishLaunchingWithOptions gives no effect,......... i call it after i make a view key and visible.

Comment: Make sure `self.window` isn't `nil` and make sure your view controllers are fully in view before calling it. It will only work on currently displayed views.

Comment: so i have it call it in every single viewController, which pretty much the same as calling it in viewDidAppear(), as there a solution like i mentioned ?

Comment: No, you call it once from anywhere when you have a need to change the font of every existing view in your app.